# Specifying Screen Reader Announcements for Textboxes

Tags: html, label, wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda

I am posting a new question after having put a few hours into searching for a solution, and reading through Similar questions.

Using NVDA, when the textbox receives focus, the label (Organization) is read, then the aria-describedby content (200 West Street, New York, NY), and then the value (Goldman Sachs):

```
<label for="organization">Organization</label>
<input type="text" id="organization" value="Goldman Sachs" aria-describedby="organizationLocation" />
<span id="organizationLocation">200 West Street, New York, NY</span>
```

For obvious reasons, in this case, it is preferred the label to be read first (Organization), then the value (Goldman Sachs), then the aria-describedby content (200 West Street, New York, NY).

I have also attempted referencing the textbox from the aria-describedby attribute, though the value of the textbox (Goldman Sachs) is repeated, being announced once after the label (Organization) and once after organizationLocation:

```
<label for="organization">Organization</label>
<input type="text" id="organization" value="Goldman Sachs" aria-describedby="organization organizationLocation" />
<span id="organizationLocation">200 West Street, New York, NY</span>
```

How difficult is it to achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally don't want to dictate how a screen reader will announce an element.  Different screen readers may announce things differently.  Did you test with JAWS or VoiceOver (Mac) to hear the order?

Elements can have an "accessible name" and an "accessible description" in addition to their role and their value.  (See [WCAG 4.1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#name-role-value) and the "[Accessible Name Computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2)").  The name and value are often announced first, and then the description, although as you noted, you are hearing the value *after* the description.  That's just how NVDA is choosing to announce it and will be the expected order by NVDA users.  If you change that order, it might confuse NVDA users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Good information, and the links were a good read as well.

I did not test with JAWS nor VoiceOver. I will see about this.

I would like for one of my coworkers to review your answer to determine if I/we have a need for further information. I should be able to get back to you by Friday morning, EDT.